# Phone forgets selected input methods?

Tags: cyanogenmod, input-methods

I have a Samsung Galaxy S+ with Cyanogenmod 10.1 (built 2013-04-15) (Kernel 3.0.73-rc1-PhenomKernel-V3).

I have turned off Google voice input in the keyboard settings because I never use it and rather have the `,` key there than voice input.

Anyways, it keeps turning itself back on (I believe when the keyboard is killed for memory) and I have to go to the settings again to turn it off.

How can I tell it to stay turned off? Can I possibly uninstall it?